# Change Image Size and position after scroll with joomla

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to make something like this http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/?theme=delawarewp with my joomla template.

I'm using ezwebhosting theme with joomla. I can handle css and html but, I'm not good at Js. I noticed there are `:before` and `:after` elements at source.

Is it something like

```
:before scroll 
div:logo{ width: 100px;} 

after: 
div:logo {width: 20px;}
```

with css. Or is there something going on with js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

these are CSS selectors, this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/ may help you